# SQL Server not recognised by PHP in xampp

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, sqlsrv

I am trying to get a database connection to a Microsoft SQL Server through XAMPP with PHP. I always get:

> Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs*****

I did download the suiting driver for my PHP version

[image: PHP Version]

I also added the driver into the php/ext folder in xampp, and configured the `php.ini` file so the 2 php_74 files will be used as extensions, one only the `_sqlsrv` file and the other `php_pdo` file. I still get this error, and the php info doesn't notice sqlsrv as a registered PHP stream on the phpinfo admin site. Anyone familiar with this error and has a solution? Thanks!

Here is the full PHP info:

[image: PHPInfo]

As well as the files in the php/ext folder:

[pdo_sqlsrv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzwlD.png)

[sqlsrv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acxXL.png)

And the `php.ini` extension additions:

[image: php.ini]

Comment: try phpinfo(), and check whether pdo_mysql module is there or not

Comment: But I dont want to use mysql, I want to use microsoft sqlserver

Comment: Ok then. Does it have pdo_sqlsrv

Comment: Did you amend the correct `php.ini`? PHP has a habit of having many ini files. For example, if you have Apache, XAMPP installed you'd like have 3 `ini` files; one of PHP itself, one for Apache and another for XAMPP. You need to ensure you update the file that your web service is using.

Comment: Did you add `extension=php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll`  and 
 `extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll` in your php.ini

Comment: It does contain the pdo_sqlsrv extension, and I also added it into the php.ini file. I edited the php.ini file which I get from the apache config, which my web service is using..

Comment: And can you shows us your connection ?

Comment: I added excatly those 2 files yes

Comment: It is not the database connection, somebody else with the same setup uses the same connection and it works for them..

Comment: @JstBrg1312 1) Restart xampp and check 2) if still not working, then share your full  phpinfo() as well as the connection string

Comment: I restarted..still not working. Which connection string do you mean? Updated the phpinfo in my question

Comment: I already have the appropriate ODBC Driver and installed it..